# Pebble Time Basalt Image Merge Pixel

Tags: pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I am wondering if you could help me complete an update to the dayworld map watch face.  I am using David Gianforte's applite code and updating for basalt.  My goal is to show the day image and when it is night to show the night image.  David's code already loops through each pixel in the picture to set night pixels to black.  I am very close but I am getting a garbled up image instead of night.  Here is my code, any thoughts?

```
//put frame buffer here

//taken from http://codecorner.galanter.net/2015/03/20/pebble-time-draw-transparent-text-over-color-bitmap-background/

GBitmap *fb = graphics_capture_frame_buffer_format(ctx, GBitmapFormat8Bit);

uint8_t *fb_data = gbitmap_get_data(fb);

uint8_t *background_data = gbitmap_get_data(gbitmap_create_with_resource(RESOURCE_ID_NIGHT_PBL));

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 144 

uint8_t (*fb_matrix)[WINDOW_WIDTH] = (uint8_t (*)[WINDOW_WIDTH]) fb_data;

uint8_t (*background_matrix)[WINDOW_WIDTH] = (uint8_t (*)[WINDOW_WIDTH]) background_data;


loop through x/y cordinates and if night{

fb_matrix[y][x] = background_matrix[y][x]; //This seems to be error

}
```

The background is perfect and the curve is in correct place but it does not accurately reflect the night image but looks like random static.  Image is 144x72.

For what it is worth, here is the original code for a black and white image to flip color when if statement is true...

```
  if ((angle < 0) ^ (0x1 & (((char *)world_bitmap->addr)[byte] >> (x % 8)))) {
    // white pixel
    ((char *)image.addr)[byte] = ((char *)image.addr)[byte] | (0x1 << (x % 8));
  } else {
    // black pixel
    ((char *)image.addr)[byte] = ((char *)image.addr)[byte] & ~(0x1 << (x % 8));
  }
```

Comment: here is a copy of my cloud pebble project, it is a bit messy so i apologize.  i keep trying to get it to work trying different code with no luck. https://github.com/pebbleben/daynight_basalt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At build time, the Pebble SDK tries to produce the smallest possible `GBitmap` for each input image you provide in your `appinfo.json` to save precious RAM at runtime. Even when running on Basalt this could mean that you end up fewer bits per pixel (e.g. `GBitmapFormat4BitPalette`) where each byte on your `background_data` could represent multiple pixels so that pixels don't necessarily start at byte-boundaries. You can use `gbitmap_get_format()` to verify this.

If this is the reason for your problem, the simplest way (at the cost of more RAM consumption) for you would be to enforce `GBitmapFormat8Bit` as your `GBitmap` format by specifying `pbi8` in your `appinfo.json`, e.g.

```json
"media": [
  {
    "type": "PBI8",
    "name": "NIGHT_PBL",
    "file": "night_globe.png"  
  }
]
```

This will produce a `GBitmapFormat8Bit` output on Basalt and `GBitmapFormat1Bit` (as before) on Aplite. Please note that you can still use the suffixes `~bw` and `~color` as described in ["Platform-specific Resources" on the 3.0 migration guide](http://developer.getpebble.com/sdk/migration-guide/#platform-specific-resources) to select different input files.

Also, try to avoid hard-coded numbers in your code. Instead of `144` use `gbitmap_get_bounds().size.w` on `fb_data` and `background_data`.

Comment: Thank you @Heiko!  I am running this on cloudpebble and I am not certain if I can edit the media type on there.  However after getting advice from two people on the pebble forum that did appear to be the issue and has been solved not through appinfo.json but by uploading a new night photo with all 64 colors added below the 72'd row.  This then forced the SDK to treat image as PBI8.  I successfully updated the current draft at github.com/pebbleben/daynight_basalt    forums.getpebble.com/discussion/23837/basalt-merge-two-images-pixel-by-pixel-for-day-night-watchface